# Implement AJAX functionality to basket

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

From Jquery I have got the product ID from the add to cart button. Whenever I click the button I have ajax code to send for the cart.php file. I assume the AJAX type is a GET request to send for this code in cart.php? I have checked console and nothing appears to execute :? I have not included the PHP code to get the $row['product_id'] as this is not the problem.

cart function - quantity details: I call this function in the basket.php.

```
function cart()
{

    //die(print_r($_SESSION));
    $total         = 0;
    $item_quantity = 0;
    $item_name     = 1;
    $item_number   = 1;
    $amount        = 1;
    $quantity      = 1;
    $shipping_cart = 3.50;

    foreach ( $_SESSION as $name => $value ) {

        if ( $value > 0 ) {

            if ( substr($name, 0, 8) == "product_" ) {
                $length = strlen($name);
                $id     = substr($name, 8, $length);
                if ( $id != 'id' ) { // This is ADDED.
                    $query = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . $id . " ");

                    confirm($query);


                    while ( $row = fetch_array($query) ) {


                        $item_quantity += $value;


                        $product_image = $row['product_image'];
                        $product_price = $row['product_price'];

                        $sub = $product_price * $value;

                        $product = <<<DELIMETER
<tr>
  <td>{$row['product_title']}<br>
  <img width='100' src='assets/images/{$product_image}'>
  </td>
  <td>&pound;{$product_price}</td>
  <td>{$value}</td>
  <td>&pound;{$sub}</td>
  <td><a class='btn btn-warning' href="cart.php?remove={$row['product_id']}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a>   <a class='btn btn-success' href="cart.php?add={$row['product_id']}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a>
<a class='btn btn-danger' href="cart.php?delete={$row['product_id']}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>        
  </tr>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_{$item_name}" value="{$row['product_title']}">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_{$item_number}" value="{$row['product_id']}">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_{$amount}" value="{$row['product_price']}">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_{$quantity}" value="{$value}">
DELIMETER;

                        echo $product;

                        $item_name++;

                        $item_number++;

                        $amount++;

                        $quantity++;
                    }

                    $fee = '5';

                    $_SESSION['item_total'] = $total += $sub;

                    $_SESSION['item_quantity'] = $item_quantity;

                   if($_SESSION['item_total'] > '100'){

                        $_SESSION['item_total'];

                   }

                    else{



                         $_SESSION['item_total'] += $fee;

                    }



                } 



        } 
    }


}

}


?>
```

This is the cart link in the header:

```
 <li style="text-decoration:none; font-size:16px; list-style-type:none; display:inline-block;"><a href="basket.php" id="cart" style='color:#fff;'><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Basket <span id="qty" class="badge"></span></a></li>
```

item.php file which includes the jQuery:

```
 <a href="cart.php?add=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-lg Prodadd" id="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" style="border-radius:2px;color:#fff;">Add to basket</a>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.Prodadd').on("click", function(){



     var qty = '<?php 
echo isset($_SESSION['item_quantity']) ? $_SESSION['item_quantity'] : $_SESSION['item_quantity'] = "0";?>';

            var product_id = $(this).attr("id");



            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "cart.php",
                data: "add":product_id,
                success: function(){

                    alert('added to basket');
                    $('#qty').html(qty);


                }


            });

            return false;



        });


                   });

    </script>
```

cart.php file:

```
<?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>

<?php


if (isset($_GET['add']) ) {

    $query = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id=" . escape_string($_GET['add']) . " ");

    confirm($query);

    while ($row = fetch_array($query) ) {

        if ($row['product_qty'] != $_SESSION[ 'product_' . $_GET['add'] ] ) {

            $_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add'] ] += 1;

            redirect("basket.php");


        } else {

            set_message3("We only have " . $row['product_qty'] . " " . "items" . " " . "of" . " " . $row['product_title'] . " " . "left in stock");

            redirect("basket.php");
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: So what is *not working*? Please show us the server-side PHP code as well.

Comment: I have showed the php code - it's below the script tags.

Comment: See here: `data: "id=" + product_id,`, it should be `data: "add=" + product_id,`. Also, you have to wrap the string in single quotes in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul changing the data works now it adds to basket without refresh. Can you tell me how I show the product_quantity beside the cart link in the header without refreshing the basket.php page. As whenever i go to basket.php with an item added the quantity in the header is zero. I have added the code for this after the question.

Comment: Remove the `redirect();` statements from the backend page. Once you've added a product in the cart, use the `success(){}` callback function to manipulate row i.e. add +1 to the product quantity and update the product row.

Comment: Thanks for helping me btw. I have removed the redirects and used the success(){} for alerting. How can I manipulate row :? sorry i'm just learning this.

Comment: I don't see any code which specifies product quantity details. Please include the *relevant* code as well.

Comment: I'll include the cart function which specifies the product quantity details. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to do, but I believe this will give you a good head start, [http://phppot.com/php/php-shopping-cart-with-jquery-ajax/](http://phppot.com/php/php-shopping-cart-with-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: I'm basically trying to append the ìtem quantity beside the cart link in the header. Now with ajax. The product adds without redirecting. I want whenever I add to append quantity 1 to the cart link.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul i have updated my ajax code to show you what I want. Using html to output the session value. Although this does not change to one it outputs to zero.

Comment: This, may be: `var quantity = Number($('#qty').html()) + 1; $('#qty').html(quantity);` in the `success(){}` callback function.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul This is what I'm looking is there a way for to keep throughout the website. In like a session?. It's whenever I leave the page the values disappear :?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul This code is exactly what I need. Thank you btw. Just need to keep the value throughout the site, if you get me?

Comment: Well, in that case you have to this value to *cart.php* page and assign it to a session variable. In this way it'd be accessible throughout the entire site.

Comment: Yeah was thinking that @RajdeepPaul thanks for all the help.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Can i use sessionStorage to save quantity value?

Comment: Yes, you can, but better you save it in the backend side session variable. It'd be easy for you to access it through out the application. Also, write an answer and *accept* it, otherwise this question will be floating around as an *open* question.